# Visual Composer Responsiveness

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, responsiveness

I'm having issues with this plugin. I'm trying to convert 3 columns to 2 columns for responsiveness in smaller devices. When ever I change the 3 columns to 2 columns from the responsive tab, it pushes the 4th item into third row. Not only that they are not positioned properly either.

This screenshot will help:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Even from your screenshot, it's hard to tell what you're talking about.  It would help to also show your 3-column layout and the 2-column layout that you want to end up with.

Comment: In the Row options, select the Equal height checkbox and see if that helps. If not, upload a screenshot of the settings for VC

Answer (score 0):

You can submit page content in VIsual Composer??